# Parse a non-top level Json array with Gson TypeToken

Tags: json, parsing, gson

I get Json-data like this:

```
{
  "crowds": [
    {
      "_id": "55ed5f87cdc20e5b2d7ba546",
      "name": "The 1 crowd"
    },
    {
      "_id": "55ed6d1a6cc793110057587d",
      "name": "testCrowd"
    },
    {
      "_id": "55ed74e2d960a18c3adb3cd7",
      "name": "The crowd"
    }
  ]
}
```

Corresponding to the `Crowd` class:

```
public class Crowd {
    private String _id;
    private String name;
}
```

And I want to turn the Json-data into a list of `Crowd` objects using Gson. The method below is derived from the official Gson examples:

```
private static Type listCrowdType = new TypeToken<List<Crowd>>(){}.getType();    
public void handleJsonResponse(String jsonString) {
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray array = jsonParser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonArray();
        List<Crowd> crowds = gson.fromJson(array.get(0), listCrowdType);
    }
```

In which case Gson tells me `This is not a JSON Array.`
I can't even count all the different ways I have tried converting the `jsonString` and passing it into Gson, but it's never happy, giving me different errors like `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_STRING` etc. 
How can it be done?

Something else I tried:

```
public void handleJsonResponse(String jsonString) {
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(jsonString);
    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

    List<Crowd> crowds = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.get("crowds"), listCrowdType);
}
```

Error: `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING`

Comment: Try removing the last comma in the list in your JSON. You currently have `}, ]`, which it may be failing to parse.

Comment: This was a mistake from me copying the JSON and removing some elements to make it easier to read. The JSON that is actually passed does not contain it.

Comment: Your last try should work fine.  Is this the only JSON your are parsing?  Is it possible the error is coming from a different attempt?

Answer (score 0):

You can try my following code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    if (!jsonObject.isNull("crowds")) {                    
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("crowds");
        Crowd[] crowdList = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), Crowd[].class);
        List<Crowd> crowds = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(crowdList));    
    }        
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps!